# How do I "go to definition" for the indexer `this[]` in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, indexer

I work with a codebase where several classes implement an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

```
public double this[int i, int j]
{
    get { return ...; }
    set { ...; }
}
```

When I stumble over code like `foo[1,2] = 3` in visual Studio 2008, I frequently want to
*right-click / "go to definition"*, i.e. show the above definition in the visual studio editor window.

For normal properties or methods this works without problems:
`foo.bar = 3`, *right-click / "go to definition"* takes me to the source code for foo.bar.
For overloaded `+` or `==` this works as well.
However with the indexer this does not seem to work. Is there any way to accomplish this?

(I cannot even search for the string "this[" in the appropriate source file, since the same syntax may be used throughout the class to access the indexer. I always have to scroll trough all the methods and properties in the dropdown list for this file)

Comment: FYI, this is called an indexer, and is not an overloaded operator.

Comment: Thanks, I was always wondering what to call this; fixed

Comment: If you have so many methods, and your class is so large, that finding this is really *that* hard you should probably look into making it a bit smaller.  Move sections of the functionality to other classes so that each class is more manageable.

Comment: it is not my framework to change, at the moment I am just trying to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really help with 2008 of course, but in 2010 and above they have "fixed" this with  the Navigate To command (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> in the C# keyboard layout).  Where you can enter `this` to show a list of indexers in the current solution where you can double-click the one you want to navigate to.

+1 for Resharper which seems to work fine with pressing F12 when you caret is within an indexer usage.

Comment: Hint: this works either when you highlight the whole expression `map[key]`, or put the cursor just after the closing `]`. Elsewhere and you're likely to go to one of the variable's declarations! (VS2010, Reshaper)

Answer (score 2):

You can install `Resharper` who give you this functionality, Tool Box productivity don't give this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will probably be to go to the definition of `foo` and see what that class is indexing.